# How Can I display an Array of Objects with a GET request using Node Js and Express For a simple RESTful API app

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, express

I'm trying to create a simple To-Do app using a RESTful API with the help of Node JS and Express. I want to be able to display an entire array of (completed tasks) along with each key and value pairs.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const data = ("/data.json")

app.use(bodyParser);



const completedTasks = [
    {id:1, task: "wash Car", dateDue:"9/20/2019", priority:2},
    {id:2, task: "Walk dog", dateDue:"9/13/2019", priority:2},
    {id:3, task: "do laundry", dateDue:"9/23/2019", priority:2},
    {id:4, task: "fix faucet", dateDue:"9/14/2019", priority:2},
    {id:5, task: "pay bills", dateDue:"9/9/2019", priority:2},
    {id:6, task: "do homework", dateDue:"9/15/2019", priority:2},
    {id:7, task: "meditate", dateDue:"9/10/2019", priority:2}
];

// Homepage
app.get("/completedTasks", (req,res) =>{
    res.write ('Homepage of ToDo App');
    res.write("\nThe Completed tasks listed below: \n");
    res.send(completedTasks.map(iterable => {
        iterable.task;
    }).join('')
    )
    // res.end()
});
       app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Listening on Port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects can not be printed directly, you need to convert it into string.

```
res.write(JSON.stringify(completedTasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
...
res.write('Homepage of ToDo App \n');
res.write("The Completed tasks listed below: \n");
completedTasks.map(iterable => {
   res.write(iterable.task +'\n')
});
res.end()
```